# Does React Native use Babel by default or is it just one option?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsx, transpiler

I know there is some sort of relationship between React Native and Babel.

What I'm not sure of is whether it's just there if I want to use it and I must enable it somehow, or whether RN always transpiles with Babel.

It must be transpiling one way or another since RN uses JSX, which is not native to any JS engine.

That makes me think it's unlikely that there would be multiple transpilation paths, one for just JSX and one for the Babel+JSX combo.

The reason I ask is because I found a newish JS function [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) that works on Android but not iOS.

Is this because the transpilation doesn't try to cover all modern JS features? Because it's a bug I should report? Something that the regular React Native transpiler doesn't handle but the Babel one would?

What exactly is the magnitude of my misunderstanding? (-:

Comment: Transpilation covers syntax, for features there are polyfills.

Comment: @pawel: Are you saying Babel only aims to do one of the two?

Comment: The core of Babel translates syntax, the Babel project also develops a polyfill https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ but I have never used it, I prefer to drop in polyfills for specific features which don't work in my target environments. One example is `[..."string"]` gets transpiled to code utilizing `Array.from`, but you may need a polyfill to make the transpiled code work in older browsers which don't implement this Array method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your'e right. React Native does get transpiled using Babel. You can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) all the babel transformers used for react native.

I don't believe you can avoid using babel, but if you wish to add transformers and plugins, you could, using you own `.babelrc` file. However, you'd still need the transformers which React Native uses, so to make it easier you could just use the [react-native babel preset](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset), which bundles for you all the transformers required by react-native. Additional transformers you would need to install and configure on your own.

Comment: Thanks! I know nothing of these transformers and plugins of which you speak, but that means my next question is whether Babel is supposed to by implementing every es6 feature and whether and how I should support the unsupported function I came across: `String.fromCodePoint`

Comment: Basically, babel transformer adds a support for a currently unsupported feature, and transforms it to plain javascript. babel plugins are just a set of transformers. I believe `String.fromCodePoint` could be supported by adding the es-2015 preset but I'm not exactly sure, I suggest you'd read more about babel and which transformers it has to offer.